# Can IIS serve my .NET app over the QUIC protocol?

Tags: iis, .net

We have a super chatty (ajax) html 5 app (gmail-like in its construction, tons of js).

The reading of QUIC sounds interesting.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC

Can IIS (or any .NET hosting engine) support QUIC?

If IIS/Win can't do it, can I do it in an haproxy instance (on CentOS) in front of IIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of August 2020, the version of IIS present in Windows 10 Version 2004 (2020-04) and Windows Server 2019 (version 19041) **does** support QUIC, and QUIC seems to be enabled by default:

[image]

Some caveats from my own observations:

- It only seems to be present in the full-fat IIS, and not IIS Express (but you wouldn't be using IIS Express in production anyway).
- HTTP/3 (QUIC) and HTTP/2 (SPDY) only seem to be enabled in a HTTPS binding and not in a plaintext HTTP binding.

  - I might be wrong - I'm not familiar with QUIC's details.
  - Note that QUIC is actually a rather low-level protocol, and that "HTTP/3" can be thought-of as "HTTP/2-over-QUIC".
- Other than the single checkbox to *disable* QUIC in the Binding settings page, I can't see any other way to configure QUIC in IIS.

Regarding the common scenario of using IIS as a front-end reverse-proxy (using IIS' URL Rewrite extension and Application Request Routing):

- I cannot find *any* information regarding support for QUIC in ARR.
- Note that the URL Rewrite Extension (which is required to use ARR) [has been recently updated to version 2.1 in 2017](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/url-rewrite-v2-1) after being stuck at version 2.0 for almost a decade. You need to [install it manually from the IIS Downloads page](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
- The ARR extension is still stuck on version 3.0 which was released in 2013.

  - This makes me think that ARR 3.0 won't support HTTP/2 (SPDY) or HTTP/3 (QUIC) - but at the same time, ARR makes use of the existing `HTTP.sys` stack in Windows, so *it's actually possible* that ARR may use HTTP/3 or HTTP/2 if available. But without an official word or tip from an insider at Microsoft it's impossible to say.

---

Additionally, [in May 2020, Microsoft announced their implementation of QUIC was open-source on GitHub](https://www.theregister.com/2020/05/04/microsoft_reveals_msquic_quic_implementation/): https://github.com/microsoft/msquic - if you have any further questions you may get answers to them there rather than through MS' official support channels or their never-updated IIS blog.

---

[I did post an Issue to the MSQuic GitHub repo seeking more information and documentation for the QUIC feature](https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/issues/735), but the issue was closed as off-topic, but they did assure me that they've forwarded the question to the internal documentation team, but doing a date-range Google search shows that no new documentation for QUIC has been published by Microsoft.

Comment: Is there any reason why I cannot see the options for QUIC in Windows Server 2019 Version 10.0.17763

Comment: @OskarSjöberg version 17663 is an old version of Windows Server (from 2018) - though it is current for LTSC/LTSB. I was using Windows Server 2019 (20H2) 19041 for my screenshot. We're up to version 1904**2** now, apparently: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/windows-server-release-info

Comment: @OskarSjöberg Correction, I was using "Windows Server, version 2004" (gah, this new nomenclature is confusing)

Comment: Dai, thank you. Do you happen to know if my Windows Server will be updated by Windows Update at some point automatically or do I need to something else to get this feature?

Comment: @OskarSjöberg Seeming as Windows Server is a server OS, it never receives major "feature updates" through Windows Update for what should be obvious reasons. All major updates must be done manually.

Comment: It make sense that this would be https bindings only because all major browsers only support HTTP/2 over HTTPS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Encryption